# Why does my CvVideoCamera cover the whole view?

Tags: ios, opencv, storyboard

I'm using a CvVideo Camera thus:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.videoCamera = [[CvVideoCamera alloc] initWithParentView:imageView];
    self.videoCamera.delegate = self;
    self.videoCamera.defaultAVCaptureDevicePosition = AVCaptureDevicePositionBack;
    self.videoCamera.defaultAVCaptureSessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetiFrame960x540;
    self.videoCamera.defaultAVCaptureVideoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientationPortrait;
    self.videoCamera.defaultFPS = 30;
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self.videoCamera start];
}
```

My storyboard looks like this:

[image]

When the view loads, the bar is visible briefly with the rest of the view white. Then when the camera starts it fills the whole screen. Why is it doing this?

Comment: self.videoCamera = [[CvVideoCamera alloc] initWithParentView:imageView]; ?? what does it do?

Comment: Is that storyboard sized for iPhone 5, and you're using a 4 or 4s? Auto-layout?

Comment: @Tom Medley: Have you found a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with a different parent view?

```
UIView *camView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 400)];
[self.view addSubview:camView];
self.videoCamera = [[CvVideoCamera alloc] initWithParentView:camView];
```